# Door hinge alignment impacting full closure

Tags: doors, outdoor, hinges

I'm having problems with a set of outdoor BBQ area doors I've installed into a frame installed in a brick space.  Basically, I have an opening constructed with two short brick walls as a space below the bench top housing the BBQ.  Against the walls I've placed some timber framing - just simple 90 x 22mm treated pine which I've aligned vertically and square to the opening.

Now the issue is that having constructed a simple door frame; a simple rectangular shape which has cement fibre sheet as the facing, I've attached a pair of easy fit hinges (i.e the ones that don't need rebating into either the door edge or the framing).  I've checked the alignment which seems ok (square and vertical etc)

The problem I'm running into is that when I push the door to close it stays open about 10-15mm as though the hinge is not closing properly.  Yet I can't see any issue with the screws which sit in countersunk holes in the hinge plates.

So do I replace with rebated hinges or is there something else that anyone would recommend to check?

Comment: Are the jambs (opening frame members) square with the wall? This sounds like there's a twist. Lay a framing square along the wall and protruding into the opening. Is the jamb in alignment with the perpendicular square leg?

Comment: A picture or two, or a diagram, would help us understand what's going on here.

Comment: it coul just be friction or it could be that the side of the door is not straight.

Comment: thanks - I'll check out the suggestions and add some pictures/diagrams to clarify